# Get-ChildItem piping Where-Object in Powershell fails?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to retrieve a certificate from my local certificate store. I started by doing something like this:

```
PS Cert:\CurrentUser\My> $cert = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\My

PS Cert:\CurrentUser\My> $cert | Where-Object {$_.Thumbprint -Match "84437"}


Directory: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::CurrentUser\My


Thumbprint                                Subject                                                                                                                                                                                    
----------                                -------                                                                                                                                                                                    
8443700000000000000000000000000000000000  CN=some certificate
```

Well. This works. So I changed it to:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\My | Where-Object {$_.Thumbprint -Match "‎84437"}
```

Yet this time I get no output at all. What's the root cause for this?

Comment: Not able to repro. What version of Windows, what version of PowerShell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first double quote in "84437" in :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\My | Where-Object {$_.Thumbprint -Match "‎84437"}
```

seems to contain 2 characters, try to delete it and you will see that you actually need to do it twice.

If we check that character using:

```
"`"‎".ToCharArray()|%{[int][char]$_}
```

The output is super weird:

```
34
8206
```

34 is the double quote, and 8206 is the weird stuff.

So just delete the double quote and and enter it again, it should work.

Comment: Nice catch. `[char]8206` seems to be [a (zero-width) formatting character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark)

Comment: Wow agreed with @MathiasR.Jessen, great catch Micky!

Comment: This is really amazing and hard to find...Thanks Micky!